# using std::move to prevent copying

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct A
{
    std::vector<int> x;

    A()
    {
        std::cout << "A()" << std::endl;
    }

    A(const A&)
    {
        std::cout << "A(const A&)" << std::endl;
    }

    ~A()
    {
        std::cout << "~A()" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct B : public A
{
    std::vector<int> y;

    B()
    {
        std::cout << "B()" << std::endl;
    }

    B(const A&a)
    {
        std::cout << "B(const A&)" << std::endl;
        x = std::move(a.x);
        y.resize(x.size());
    }

    B(const A&&a)
    {
        std::cout << "B(const A&&)" << std::endl;
        x = std::move(a.x);
        y.resize(x.size());
    }
    B(const B&)
    {
        std::cout << "B(const B&)" << std::endl;
    }

    ~B()
    {
        std::cout << "~B()" << std::endl;
    }
};

A ret_a()
{
    A a;
    a.x.resize(10);
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "section I" << std::endl << std::endl;

    A a = ret_a();  
    B b(a);
    std::cout << "a.x.size=" << a.x.size() << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::endl << "section II" << std::endl << std::endl;

    B b2(ret_a());
    std::cout << "b.x.size=" << b.x.size() << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::endl << "section III" << std::endl << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

With output (VS2013, Release build)

```
section I

A()
A()
B(const A&)
a.x.size=10

section II

A()
A()
B(const A&&)
~A()
b.x.size=10

section III

~B()
~A()
~B()
~A()
~A()
```

1. Why a.x.size() within "section I" has size 10? I thought that std::move should move all data from a.x to y.x
2. Why did "section II" call constructor A() twice? I thought that B(const A&&) would prevent excessive copying of A

**UPDATE**

see fixed code at http://pastebin.com/70Nmt9sT

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `T&&` and `const T&&` are not the same type. You almost never want a `const` rvalue reference - you can't steal its resources since you made it `const`! `x = std::move(a.x);` in `B(const A&a)` copies `a.x` since the return type of [`std::move(a.x)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) is `const vector<int>&&`.
2. The constructor, `B(const A&&)` calls the default constructor of `A` since it is derived from `A`, and the member initializer list does not make an attempt to construct the base `A`. This is the second `A` call.

Answer (score 2):

> Why `a.x.size()` within "section I" has size 10? I thought that `std::move` should move all data from `a.x` to `y.x`

This is because of `B(const A&& a)`. Since `a` is `const` within that constructor, you only have `const` access to its member `x`, and calling `std::move` on a `vector<T> const` results in a `vector<T> const&&` which cannot bind to `vector`'s move constructor (which takes a `vector<T>&&` argument). Instead it ends up calling the copy constructor, which leaves the source object unmodified.

> Why did "section II" call constructor `A()` twice? I thought that `B(const A&&)` would prevent excessive copying of `A`

The first default construction occurs within the body of `ret_a()`. The second default construction is that of the `A` sub-object of `B`. To avoid the second one `move` the `A` instance in the member initializer list.

```
B(const A&&a)
: A(std::move(a))
{
    std::cout << "B(const A&&)" << std::endl;
    y.resize(x.size());
}
```

Note that the `move` doesn't actually result in moving the contents of `a` due to the same reason as explained above. Moreover, even modifying the signature to `B(A&& a)` would not result in the contents of `a` being moved because the user provided copy constructor and destructor definitions prevent implicit generation of a move constructor for `A`, and it'll be copied instead.